# Moving Specific Word Within Sentence in A Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, replace

I have this dataset:

| Column A |
| --- |
| pt abcdefg |
| cv fghikl |
| abcdg pt |
| opqrs cv |
| bp ststst |
| qwert bp |

I want the word 'pt', 'cv', and 'bp' to the last of the sentence, so this is the output that I want:

| Column A |
| --- |
| abcdefg pt |
| fghikl cv |
| abcdg pt |
| opqrs cv |
| ststst bp |
| qwert bp |

I haven't tried any code but I found this code but I'm stuck in modifying it since I want to apply it to the whole DataFrame.

```
def order_word(s, word, delta):
        words = s.split()
        oldpos = words.index(word)
        words.insert(oldpos+delta, words.pop(oldpos))
        return ' '.join(words)
```

Can anyone help me to build the code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: pt and cv always are seperated with others by white space?

Comment: @PandaKim Yes, they are

Comment: Does the following case exist? 'aa pt cccc' -> 'aa cccc pt'?

Comment: @PandaKim no, the words only exist either at the beginning or at the end of the sentence

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex with [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
df['Column A'] = df['Column A'].str.replace(r'\s*\b(cv|pt|bp)\b\s*(.*$)',
                                            r'\2 \1', regex=True)
```

Output (as new column for clarity):

```
     Column A    Column B
0  pt abcdefg  abcdefg pt
1   cv fghikl   fghikl cv
2    abcdg pt    abcdg pt
3    opqrs cv    opqrs cv
4   bp ststst   ststst bp
5    qwert bp    qwert bp
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/E5exo5/1)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a proposition using [`pandas.Series.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/fr/3/library/functions.html#sorted) :

```
df["Column A"] = (
                    df["Column A"]
                        .str.split()
                        .apply(lambda x: " ".join(sorted(x, key=len, reverse=True)))
                  )
```

##### # Output :

```
print(df)
     Column A
0  abcdefg pt
1   fghikl cv
2    abcdg pt
3    opqrs cv
4   ststst bp
5    qwert bp
```

Comment: This is not really specific to matching pt/cv/bp ;)

Comment: Ayy, I underestimated OP's dataset. I'll think of a solution to re-adapt my answer..

Answer (score 0):

**Example**

```
data = {'Column A': {0: 'pt abcdefg',1: 'cv fghikl',2: 'abcdg pt',3: 'opqrs cv',4: 'bp ststst',5: 'qwert bp',6: 'aaaa pt cc'}}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

`df`:

```
    Column A
0   pt abcdefg
1   cv fghikl
2   abcdg pt
3   opqrs cv
4   bp ststst
5   qwert bp
6   aaaa pt cc
```

**Code**

```
s = (df['Column A'].str.replace(r'(.*)(pt|cv|bp)(.*)', r'\1 \3 \2', regex=True)
   .str.replace(r'(\s)+', r'\1', regex=True))
```

output(`s`):

```
0    abcdefg pt
1     fghikl cv
2      abcdg pt
3      opqrs cv
4     ststst bp
5      qwert bp
6    aaaa cc pt
dtype: object
```

make `s` to column

I made this code for case that pt or cv would exist in middle.

---

**Update**

questioner say doesnt exist case  in middle.

then use following code:

```
df['Column A'].str.replace(r'^(pt|cv|bp)[ ](.+)', r'\2 \1', regex=True)
```